# How to sum consecutive identical numbers in a list in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I have a list like this:

```
a:1 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 4 4 4 5 6 4
```

How can I sum all of the consecutive identical numbers in `a`, so that it will become:

```
a:4 2 3 2 12 5 6 4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways - one method:

```
q) a:1 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 4 4 4 5 6 4
q) sum each where[differ a] _ a
    4 2 3 2 12 5 6 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to achieve this using `prev` & `<>`:

```
sum each cut[where a<>prev[a]; a]
4 2 3 2 12 5 6 4
```